# WordPress allow PHP tags in html editor - surrounding html tags with if else statement

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

I have searched for hours and I can't make this work.

The plugin is supposed to let you type `[php]` and `[/php]` tags surrounding your php code which allows it to function in a tinymce html editor.

It works properly like this:

```
[php] echo "test"; [/php]
```

But doesn't work when I try to break up the code and surround html:

```
[php] if ($_REQUEST['tabx'] == "1") { [/php] 
<div>[schoolsearch location_title="" lat="" lng" distance="3" groupby="gradelevel" output="table"]</div>
[php] } [/php]
```

I'm trying to accomplish doing an if/else statement inside the html editor and only way I can think of is using these php tags.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<div>[php] if ($_REQUEST['tabx'] == "1") 
    { echo "[schoolsearch location_title='' lat= lng='' distance='3' groupby='gradelevel' output='table']";
} [/php] </div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I did try that earlier and the entire DIV contents just disappears. I believe it has something to do with escaping brackets or quotes when inside an echo.  It didn't work.  :(

Comment: Thank you.  It just isn't working.  I was meaning the brackets as in `[]`.  I tried putting a slash before each of those or slash before the single quotes.  Still not working.  Thank you for your efforts.